# how to replace a specific char in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting

I want to replace a specific char in a file. for example, I have a 20 line file and I want to replace the letter a on the 5th line and 12th column.
example:
what I have on line 5 `hello world!`
and I want to replace the `!` with `?`

This cannot be done with a search and replace method because the actual text in the file is more or less random or changes frequently. I need to specify the unknown char at line 5 column 12, then replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Edit - better answers than mine:

From @Cyrus:

```
sed -E '5 s/(.{11})./\1?/' your_file
```

From @potong:

```
sed '5s/./?/12' your_file
```

##### My original answer (just to contrast with the cleaner approaches)

This will do it:

```
sed '5 s/\(.\{11\}\).\(.*\)/\1?\2/' your_file
```

The ways it's working is as follows:

- On line 5, perform a substitution
- I remember the stuff in between the above using `\(` and `\)`
- The first remembered part matches 11 characters of any type `.\{11\}`
- Then a single characters of any type is matched (in your case that will be
  the '!')
- The second remembered part matches everything after the single character`\{.*\}`
- Then we put back the remembered content `\1` and `\2`
- But we replace the single matched character with a question mark

Once you've confirmed it does what you want, you can add the `-i` to do the
substitution in-place:

```
sed -i '5 s/\(.\{11\}\).\(.*\)/\1?\2/' your_file
```

If we use the extended expressions flag (`-E`) we don't have to escape so much
stuff:

```
sed -E '5 s/(.{11}).(.*)/\1?\2/' your_file
```

Comment: I think you can trim it down a bit: `sed -E '5 s/(.{11})./\1?/' your_file`

Comment: Perhaps `sed '5s/./?/12' file`?